# Is it possible to get the whole source code of a jsp page including the java code within tags in it from a webpage?

Tags: java, security, jsp

I wanted to know if there is a way or ways to get the whole source code of a JSP page, which means the HTML code and the JAVA code within the tags, using any tools or any libraries. I know its possible to get the HTML code programatically. But I am not sure if one can get the JAVA code also. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am talking with respect to application security.

Comment: Misconfigured server is the most possible way to get the page in its original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you have access to jsp, it is not possible. JSP/Java code will be translated HTML before sending to browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a long time ago, but I'd like to point out that there was a [very well documented](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2001-1511) container vulnerability on JRun that allowed you to see the full JSP source code.

http://server/page.js%2570

Where %25 is a URL Encoded "%" and 70 is the hexadecimal value for p.

Comment: Provide a link to a description of the vulnerability (in CVE and/or Apache).

Comment: Here is a link @erickson: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2001-1511

Comment: That's for JRun, which I think may have been obsolete by the time you were born. But I edited it into your answer.